# Find points in the same direction

Tags: python, geopandas

Given a vector of two points with direction from point 1 to point 2:

```
latitude_1 longitud_1 latitude_2 longitud_2
41.378118   2.169557   41.389474    2.156421
```

Find points in the dataset that are in the same "direction":

```
Latitude Longitud 
41.383093   2.181116
41.373258   2.159358
41.385252   2.168779
41.390692   2.148911
```

In the image below, the 3 red points in front of the vector would be in the same direction.
For direction we can divide 360 degrees in 6 equal parts. A 4 part split is also good.

Expected output would be:

```
latitude_1 longitud_1 latitude_2 longitud_2   Number of points
41.378118   2.169557   41.389474    2.156421  1
```

Things I have tried with a 4 quadrant split:

```
def relative_location(row):
    if row["lat_dif"] > 0 and row["long_dif"] > 0:
        return "North East"
    elif row["lat_dif"] < 0 and row["long_dif"] > 0:
        return "South East"
    elif row["lat_dif"] > 0 and row["long_dif"] < 0:
        return "North West"
    elif row["lat_dif"] < 0 and row["long_dif"] < 0:
        return "South West"
    elif row["lat_dif"] == 0 and row["long_dif"] < 0:
        return "West"
    elif row["lat_dif"] == 0 and row["long_dif"] > 0:
        return "East"
    elif row["lat_dif"] > 0 and row["long_dif"] == 0:
        return "North"
    elif row["lat_dif"] < 0 and row["long_dif"] == 0:
        return "South"
    else: return "Same point"

df["relative_location"] = df.apply(relative_location, axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: In your graphic, the 0 or 360° position is not correct (mathematical and not geographic)

Comment: You can use a clustering algorithm like [kmeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) or [DBscan](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) (I thinks is more adapt for this case) for regroup the points according their angle with the reference point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using pyproj:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj
import numpy as np

geodesic = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84') #See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873868/python-calculate-bearing-between-two-lat-long

df = gpd.read_file('/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/random_points.shp')

#Find azimuth of the two points by using their indexes
p1 = df.iloc[2595]
p2 = df.iloc[3110]
fwd_azimuth_goal,back_azimuth,distance = geodesic.inv(p1.geometry.x, p1.geometry.y, 
                                                 p2.geometry.x, p2.geometry.y)
#fwd_azimuth_goal
#Out[36]: 50.920292718041104

#Find azimuth from the first point to all other points and add as column
az = []
for ix in df.index.tolist():
    fwd_azimuth,back_azimuth,distance = geodesic.inv(df.iloc[2595].geometry.x, df.iloc[2595].geometry.y,
                                                     df.iloc[ix].geometry.x, df.iloc[ix].geometry.y)
    az.append(fwd_azimuth)
df['az'] = az

df['match'] = np.where((df['az']<fwd_azimuth_goal+5)&(df['az']>fwd_azimuth_goal-5),1,0)
df.to_file('/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/random_points_result.shp')
```

Filter match=1:
[image]